# DotNetZip Exception Bad state (invalid literal/length code)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnetzip

NET MVC 4 application and in this app I have to download multiple files represented by a List of byte arrays  in a Zip file , so I used the DotNetZip library. when I execute this piece if code :

```
 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
       {
        using (var archive = new ZipFile())
        {
         foreach (var item in byteArrays)
         {
          var entry = archive.AddEntry("file" + i + ".pdf", item);
          i++;
          archive.Save("All.zip");
           using (var zipStream = entry.OpenReader())
           {
           zipStream.Write(item, 0, item.Length);
          }
         }
        }
        return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/zip", "all.zip");
        }
```

at this line :

```
zipStream.Write(item, 0, item.Length);
```

I got this error :

> Bad state (invalid literal/length code)
>
> Ionic.Zlib.ZlibException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233088   Message=Bad state (invalid literal/length code) 
>   Source=DotNetZip   StackTrace:
>          at Ionic.Zlib.InflateManager.Inflate(FlushType flush)
>          at Ionic.Zlib.ZlibCodec.Inflate(FlushType flush)
>          at Ionic.Zlib.ZlibBaseStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>          at Ionic.Zlib.DeflateStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>          at Ionic.Crc.CrcCalculatorStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>          at Host.Web.Areas.FranceArea.Controllers.FranceController.downloadMultiplefile()
>   in
>   C:\Projects\Oddo.Web.OBAM_Icn\Host\Host.Web\Areas\FranceArea\Controllers\FranceController.cs:line
>   503
>          at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.b__41()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult
>   _)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49()
>   InnerException:

Comment: Open reader and write ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `zipStream.Write`, as you have passed the data in the `.AddEntry` call already.

This works for me:

```
var i = 1;

using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var archive = new ZipFile())
    {
        foreach (var item in byteArrays)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(item))
            {
                var entry = archive.AddEntry($"file{i++}.pdf", ms);
                archive.Save(outStream);
            }
        }
    }
    outStream.Position = 0;
    return File(outStream.ToArray(), "application/zip", "all.zip");
}
```

Comment: Thank  you for your response  , it worked to download the archive  but when I open the zip and try to open or extract the files i found out that the files cannot be opened because it is corrupted ... what is the cause of such problem ?

Comment: You could check that your byte arrays are valid pdfs, Also check whether the files in the zip have the same lengths as your byte arrays

Comment: Yes when i opened the archive and checked the size of the files i can see that they kept their initial size that means that there is no lost data :/ but the problem still there